# Android data file transfer by vibration- No WIFI

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-sensors

I want to transfer a file between 2 android device by generating vibration. I have a text message and I encode the message to Morse code. Then I generate vibration patterns in the sender device. I want the Receiver android device to get the vibration and decode it to Morse code. Is there anybody that can help with that?

Comment: This question is MUCH too broad for StackOverflow's standards. You're basically asking us to write an entire app. The idea is interesting, but you need to start and ask questions about specific roadblocks, not how to make the entire app. If you don't know where to start, find an Android tutorial and learn the basics first, and THEN come to StackOverflow for things that you don't understand (and make sure to search to see if your question has been answered before you ask).

Comment: My problem is that if I should use the accelerometer sensor to detect the vibration? If so, how can I use this sensor to only detect the vibrations?

Comment: Actually, I guess the main question is, how do I detect vibrations? Almost all other examples on the net is about how to detect shakes and movement.